# Selecting single items from MVC enumerable models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

when using a MVC 3 collection that uses IEnumerable, is there a way to make small queries work to find single values? I've been experimenting with little success.

I have a collection of settings that have descriptions and settings. The problem is exposing one of them, as each is unique. I've tried something like this:

```
var appl = _service.GetSettings(id, app); //Call to service layer & repository
appl.Select(a => a.setting_value.Where(a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login")));
```

With little success (unless I'm missing something). Is it possible to select one item from an enumerable collection and either pass it to a ViewBag or ViewData object? What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
var appl = _service.GetSettings(id, app); //Call to service layer & repository
ViewBag.Login = appl.Select(a => a.setting_value.Where(a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login")));
```

And pass this to the view, since I have a view that now combines a collection with single values.

The following seems to work within the view:

```
Application Name @Html.TextBox("application_name", @Model.FirstOrDefault().app_name)
```

But I'm not sure if this violates separation of concerns. Am I on the wrong path here? Thank you!

EDIT: Here is what I needed. The answers below got me very very close +1 +1

```
ViewBag.Login = appl.Where(a => a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login")).FirstOrDefault().setting_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var appl = _service.GetSettings(id, app);
ViewBag.Login = appl
    .Where(a => a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's great... it doesn't give me any errors but it only returns my class name on the view... I'm sure there's something I'm doing wrong. I tried other operators, such as "Equals," but I only get the class name. Hm. But thank you!

Comment: Ok, what I needed was one more dot. This gives me exactly what I want: ViewBag.Login = appl.Where(a => a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login")).FirstOrDefault().setting_value; Sorry if I wasn't clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewBag.Login = appl.Select(a => a.setting_value.Where(a.setting_name.StartsWith("Login"))).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will select the first object that matches your criteria and return a single result or null

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but when I insert that into my code, I receive 2 compile errors: 1. 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments." 2. cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Func<char,bool>'. Also, Select and Where both have red lines under them  - both tell me to "specify type arguments explicitly."